# Find all values of $n$ which satisfy the above equation where $n>1$ and $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $$ \frac14+\frac19+\frac1{16}+...+\frac1{n^2}=\frac7{12}-\frac1{n+1}$$ Find all values of $n$ which satisfy the above equation where $n>1$ and $n$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.

My attempt$:$ $$ \frac14+\frac19+\frac1{16}+...+\frac1{n^2}=\frac7{12}-\frac1{n+1}$$ $\implies$ $$ \frac14+\frac19+\frac1{16}+...+\frac1{n^2}=\frac{7n+7-12}{12n+12}$$ $\implies$ $$ \frac14+\frac19+\frac1{16}+...+\frac1{n^2}=\frac{7n-5}{12n+2}$$ Now the denominator $12n+12$ must be a square number. So by plugging values we can see that $n=2$ is a solution.

Second method$:$

Since $7n+5$ is any positive integer and simultaneously $n$ is also a positive integer. So we can check for what values of $7n+5$ is the value of $n$ an integer. By this I got the solution that $7n+5=19$ or again $n=2$.

I think that either of these methods are merely hit$-$and$-$trial and so I want to know a solution which finds the values of $n$ mathematically. And also $n=2$ is the only possible integer solution.
And also $n\ge16$ because after that the sum will exceed $\frac7{12}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is  $\frac1{n+1}=\frac13$

Comment: Why must $12n+12$ be a square?  Do you have reason to believe $\frac{7n-5}{12n+12}$ is always in lowest terms?  Also, why do the various sums on the left have square denominators?  When $n = 10$, the denominator of the sum on the left, in lowest terms, is $2^6 3^4 5^1 7^2$, which is not square.

Comment: Oh I didn't have a proof of this thanks for this should I edit this?

Comment: I would leave your attempted solution(s) in the Question, but might add where you know there are gaps in your arguments.

Comment: You should be able to show (by direct calculation, if necessary) that the left-hand sum with $n = 16$ is greater than $7/12$, so there is no such $n \geq 16$.  That leaves (at worst) fourteen values of $n$ to check for equality.

Comment: Yeah I didn't thought that

Comment: Please tell anybody